# Debugging in PHP using ajax and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, debugging, error-handling

I am using `$.ajax` to submit requests to a PHP function from jQuery. Obviously, I have a problem in one of my functions, since it is not producing results.

Putting `die()`, `header()` or `exit()` in my PHP code does not work. I need something I can use to debug my code. Any suggestions?

Here is the ajax...

```
/************ Update Job Status ************/
$('.update-job-status').on('change', function() {
    var status = $(this).val();
    var id = $(this).parent().children('#id').val();

    var formData = "id="+id+"&status="+status;

    $.ajax({ // Start the PHP submission
                url : "/resources/submit.php?action=updateJobStatus",
                type: "POST",
                data : formData,
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {    //data - response from server
                    $('.notification-success').css('display', 'block').append('Status was updated!');
                    $('.notification-success').fadeOut(2000, function(){
                        $(this).empty();
                    });
                }
            });
});
```

submit.php is a middle man, just a handoff to the correct PHP script, this is where the work is done.

```
function updateJobStatus($id, $status) {
            global $databaseController;

            //I want to put something here to kill it.
            $sql = 'UPDATE jobs SET status="' . $status . '" WHERE id="' . $id . '"';
            $didHappen = $databaseController->update($sql);


            return $didHappen;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/)?

Comment: Use the `error` callback

Comment: You could access the page directly. Use a `debug=true` querystring value to write out messages

Comment: @Machavity I have not.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ That would only tell me that it failed, not where it failed, right?

Comment: @jwatts1980 could you elaborate, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Could you please paste the relevant parts of your code here as an example, so we can more effectively help you with your specific problem?

Comment: Sorry, I had assumed that the "function" you were referring to was a PHP function on a PHP page that you are calling via AJAX. If that is the case, then you can browse to that PHP directly and view the output directly in the browser window instead of having to get through it through an AJAX return. Further, by manually adding `?debug=true` to the querystring, you can read that value in the PHP code and use it to output greater detail about which steps you're in, function inputs, and so on.

Comment: @esqew I added the code to the question.